# rCharts dPlot - How I increase area of the chart to 900 width/ 800 height and how to add Chart Title?

Tags: r, rcharts

dPlots are wonderful and I am able to show huge amount of data very intuitively in seconds. I like it. Now I want to display that chart in bigger iframe. I tried to change height/width of dPlot no luck. I also like to add Title to chart. Please help.

I am using below sample code (the code provided by timelyportfolio (via github)
Title: Build the Chart and Test iframe 
weblink: https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/230

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code to show how to modify width of the chart.

```
library(rCharts)
titanic <- as.data.frame(Titanic)
d1 <- dPlot(
    Freq ~ Sex,
    groups = "Survived",
    data = titanic,
    type = "bar"
)
d1$set(width = 1200)
```

I tested it on my laptop and it works. You need the `dev` branch of `rCharts` to run this.

Comment: Thanks Ramnath. Now Chart size increased but dimples are not reacting while I am clicking. I am using "d1$templates$script="http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_dimple/assets/chart_legend.html" Am I diong right?

Comment: Can anyone help me how I get interactive dimples or how I add javascript please? I am not a programmer and appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: I have opened an [issue on rCharts GitHub](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/324) that would give more flexibility to this task.